# recommendation of map viewer

Tags: openstreetmap, open-source-gis, java, software-recommendations, windows-7

I am looking for software to present GIS files (OSM preferred) with these features:

1. work offline (means I can download a map and present it online in the software).
2. compatible with Windows 7, 32 bit.
3. open source code available in Java so I can add it into a desktop app.
4. editor is preferred as I would like to add 2 features to this map (a balloon with information and fixed length range circle).

Answer (score 1):

Openlayers should fit your need, but I don't know what kind of "gis files" you want to deal with.

Consuming and displaying 256x256px tiles is easy, but storing a whole country offline will slow down any application.

Comment: actually yes, it is suppose to present a country (a small one).
at first I thought of using osm but I'm open to suggestions...

Comment: If you don't need access to raw data then [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) plus OpenLayers or Leaflet will be enough.

Comment: You have the choice between raster tiles and vector tiles. Both can be made from Openstreetmap data. If you filter out data you do not want to display, vector format can be smaller than raster tiles. The osm wiki lists several ways of implementation.